# How to show hidden table rows using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple table with 5 rows. 1st row is only visible and last 4row are hidden.

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
   <th>sr</th> 
   <th>Head</th>
  </tr> 
 <tr style="display:block;"> 
   <td>1</td> 
   <td>row 1</td> 
 </tr > 
<tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>2</td> 
  <td>row 2</td> 
 </tr> 
<tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>3</td> 
  <td>row 3</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>4</td> 
  <td>row 4</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>5</td> 
  <td>row 5</td> 
 </tr> 
 </table>
 <button id="add">Add row</button>
 <button>Remove row</button>
```

javascript 
what i have try

```
$('#add').click(function() {
rows.show();
});
```

When click on add row the 2nd row should show and so no
and when click on remove row it should hide the latest row and so on

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: and where is your javascript code?

Comment: no, i have not try JavaScript

Comment: try to solve it first then come back if you stuck in something. SO is not a code me project mate sorry

Comment: i have tired the bootstrap toggle for hide show but only 2nd row gets toggled

Comment: Show the code you have tried with, so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the first `hidden tr` using  and last `visible tr` like this

```js
$(document).on('click','#add',function(){

  $('table tbody').find('tr:hidden:first').show();

});
$(document).on('click','#remove',function(){

  $('table tbody').find('tr:visible:last:not(:first-child)').hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
  <tr> 
   <th>sr</th> 
   <th>Head</th>
  </tr> 
  <tbody>
 <tr style="display:block;"> 
   <td>1</td> 
   <td>row 1</td> 
 </tr > 
<tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>2</td> 
  <td>row 2</td> 
 </tr> 
<tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>3</td> 
  <td>row 3</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>4</td> 
  <td>row 4</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr style="display:none;"> 
   <td>5</td> 
  <td>row 5</td> 
 </tr> 
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <button id="add">Add row</button>
 <button id="remove">Remove row</button>
```

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @RahulMohite

Comment: how can it prevent 1st row to remove from table

Comment: is it possible to prevent 1st row from getting removing

Comment: yeah possible just wait a minute @RahulMohite

Comment: hey @JYoThI  what happend?

Comment: coooool :)  glad to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145683/discussion-between-rahul-mohite-and-jyothi).

Answer (score 1):

Check if below code works!

I have added id to add and remove buttons.

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () { 
  $("table tr:hidden:first").show();
});

$('#btnRemove').click(function () {
   if($("table tr:visible").length !== 2) {
     $("table tr:visible:last").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: its works but how to prevent 1st row to get removing

Comment: Try putting your required use cases in question. Thanks!

Comment: oh sure from next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery function to find hidden tr:

```
var hiddenTRs = $("tr:hidden");
```

then you can show of of them with:

```
hiddenTRs.first().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pure jQuery solution

You could change your buttons

```
<button data-action="add">Add row</button>
<button data-action="remove">Remove row</button>
```

and now you can use this script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('button[data-action]').on('click', function() {

    // which button is pressed?
    if ($(this).data('action') == 'add') {

      // show 'tr' of all 'td'
      $('table td').parent().css('display', 'block');
    } else {

      // hide'tr' of all 'td'
      $('table td').parent().css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

### Bootstrap solution

Change your table rows

```
<tr style="height: 0px;"> 
  <td>5</td> 
  <td>row 5</td>
</tr>
```

Now you can use this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('button[data-action]').on('click', function() {

    // which button is pressed?
    if ($(this).data('action') == 'add') {

      // show 'tr' of all 'td'
      $('table td').parent().collapse('show');
    } else {

      // hide'tr' of all 'td'
      $('table td').parent().collapse('hide');
    }
  });
});
```